# Error building quantlib test suite/ piecewise yield curve tests: ASX futures failure

Tags: build, installation, quantlib

I'm building Quantlib 1.9 with Visual Studio Professional 2015 (MSVC 14) - Release x64. Why am I getting the following errors?

```
2>piecewiseyieldcurve.cpp(510): error : in "QuantLib test suite/Piecewise yield curve tests/QuantLib__detail__quantlib_test_case(&PiecewiseYieldCurveTest__testLogLinearDiscountConsistency)": 2nd ASX futures failure:
2>    estimated rate: 4.57072220 %
2>    expected rate:  4.57300000 %
2>  Testing consistency of piecewise-linear discount curve...
2>piecewiseyieldcurve.cpp(510): error : in "QuantLib test suite/Piecewise yield curve tests/QuantLib__detail__quantlib_test_case(&PiecewiseYieldCurveTest__testLinearDiscountConsistency)": 2nd ASX futures failure:
2>    estimated rate: 4.57068683 %
2>    expected rate:  4.57300000 %
2>  Testing consistency of piecewise-linear zero-yield curve...
2>piecewiseyieldcurve.cpp(510): error : in "QuantLib test suite/Piecewise yield curve tests/QuantLib__detail__quantlib_test_case(&PiecewiseYieldCurveTest__testLinearZeroConsistency)": 2nd ASX futures failure:
2>    estimated rate: 4.57105482 %
2>    expected rate:  4.57300000 %
2>  Testing consistency of piecewise-cubic zero-yield curve...
2>piecewiseyieldcurve.cpp(510): error : in "QuantLib test suite/Piecewise yield curve tests/QuantLib__detail__quantlib_test_case(&PiecewiseYieldCurveTest__testSplineZeroConsistency)": 2nd ASX futures failure:
2>    estimated rate: 4.57134932 %
2>    expected rate:  4.57300000 %
2>  Testing consistency of piecewise-linear forward-rate curve...
2>piecewiseyieldcurve.cpp(510): error : in "QuantLib test suite/Piecewise yield curve tests/QuantLib__detail__quantlib_test_case(&PiecewiseYieldCurveTest__testLinearForwardConsistency)": 2nd ASX futures failure:
2>    estimated rate: 4.57115379 %
2>    expected rate:  4.57300000 %
2>  Testing consistency of piecewise-flat forward-rate curve...
2>piecewiseyieldcurve.cpp(510): error : in "QuantLib test suite/Piecewise yield curve tests/QuantLib__detail__quantlib_test_case(&PiecewiseYieldCurveTest__testFlatForwardConsistency)": 2nd ASX futures failure:
2>    estimated rate: 4.57072220 %
2>    expected rate:  4.57300000 %
2>  Testing consistency of convex monotone forward-rate curve...
2>piecewiseyieldcurve.cpp(510): error : in "QuantLib test suite/Piecewise yield curve tests/QuantLib__detail__quantlib_test_case(&PiecewiseYieldCurveTest__testConvexMonotoneForwardConsistency)": 2nd ASX futures failure:
2>    estimated rate: 4.57129291 %
2>    expected rate:  4.57300000 %
2>  Testing consistency of local-bootstrap algorithm...
2>piecewiseyieldcurve.cpp(510): error : in "QuantLib test suite/Piecewise yield curve tests/QuantLib__detail__quantlib_test_case(&PiecewiseYieldCurveTest__testLocalBootstrapConsistency)": 2nd ASX futures failure:
2>    estimated rate: 4.57129291 %
2>    expected rate:  4.57300000 %
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in the test suite. Check the following link:
https://sourceforge.net/p/quantlib/mailman/message/35654704/

Comment: Yes. I might do a quick 1.9.2 release to fix it.